# Installing oracle on core i5 processor - performance

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g, intel

I am planning to buy a new laptop and my concern is will oracle 11g work on CORE i5 processor, 8GB RAM laptop without having any hanging problems or other issues? I came to know that after installing oracle 10g/11g system will hang or become slow. I had this same experience with core i3 processor laptops. Anybody have any idea about this?

Comment: I've run Oracle on several laptops and desktops with much less resources.  Oracle has been selling Personal Edition before that processor existed.  You should be fine if it's configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that laptop doesn't run any other resource hug, if the disks are not super-slow (because they may be old, fragmented, etc.), and if that database is not very big on itself, and if no more than 1 or 2 sessions get connected to it, 8Gig and i5 should be OK. Less seems not good, particularly the memory. Know that you can (and need) to tune the database memory usage anyway.